# Is it possible to use error as an output?

Tags: python, error-handling, output

I want to design a function where error can be used as an output and does not terminate the whole code. I want to use the value of the element at which the error occur and return it. Is there keyword or any way for that?

Comment: Could you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`try`/`except`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html) to catch exceptions.

The code below shows you how to catch any exception and get the value. You can read the documentation page on [handling exceptions](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions).

```
import sys
try:
    non_existing # this usually raises a NameError
except:
    e = sys.exc_info()[0]
    print(e)
```

output: `<class 'NameError'>`

Comment: thanks. I was stuck at it for quite some time

Answer (score 0):

Well what you are trying to do is certainly possible.

```
def fun(a,b):
    try :
        c = a/b
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return a

print(fun(10,0))
```

**OUTPUT** 10

In the except block you can access any info that was there in the try block, like a or b. But you cannot access those variable like c which was never made since the exception occurred before it was made. Mostly what you are trying to do should be possible with this, with just a little bit of tweaks. If you want to except only some specific type of error. Then you use type(e) and then check it's parent class and then put it there instead of "Exception" class.